# greenplum6.9 gpexpand occurred error,but no error log

Tags: greenplum

```
20201118:18:13:10:008884 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Configuring new segments (primary)
20201118:18:13:10:008884 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[INFO]:-{'slave34': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg17:6002:true:false:19:17::-1:', 'slave33': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg16:6002:true:false:18:16::-1:', 'slave32': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg15:6002:true:false:17:15::-1:', 'slave31': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg14:6002:true:false:16:14::-1:', 'slave28': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg12:6002:true:false:14:12::-1:', 'slave29': '/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg13:6002:true:false:15:13::-1:'}
20201118:18:13:42:008884 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-gpexpand failed: ExecutionError: 'Error Executing Command: ' occurred.  Details: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 slave33 ". /usr/local/greenplum-db-6.9.0/greenplum_path.sh; env GPSESSID=0000000000 GPERA=None $GPHOME/bin/pg_ctl -D /opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg16 -l /opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg16/pg_log/startup.log -w -t 600 -o \" -p 6002 -c gp_role=utility -M \" start 2>&1"'  cmd had rc=1 completed=True halted=False
  stdout='waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
'
  stderr='' 

Exiting...
20201118:18:13:42:008884 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[ERROR]:-Please run 'gpexpand -r' to rollback to the original state.
20201118:18:13:42:008884 gpexpand:master27:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Shutting down gpexpand...
```

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: There isn't enough here to help. You need to look at the pg_log files on these new nodes.

Comment: 2020-11-19 10:06:03.041794 CST,,,p8067,th458434688,,,,0,,,seg12,,,,,"LOG","F0000","authentication option not in name=value format: host",,,,,"line 100 of configuration file ""/opt/data/gpdatap3/gpseg12/pg_hba.conf""",,0,,"hba.c",1290,
2020-11-19 10:06:03.042010 CST,,,p8067,th458434688,,,,0,,,seg12,,,,,"FATAL","F0000","could not load pg_hba.conf",,,,,,,0,,"postmaster.c",1460,     no file pg_hba.conf   Any Help? Thank you very much.

Comment: The error states that the format of you file isn't right. Can you provide more detail like the command you ran and the configuration file?